# Как разобрать вложенные словари в столбцы по ключам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, словари, обработка-данных

Имею список с вложенными словарями:

```
[
    {'A': {'ABC': '1234', 'QWE': '2342'}},
    {'B': {'ABC': '234', 'QWE': '3424', 'RTY': 'qwert'}},
    {'A': {'ABC': '2342', 'QWE': '23424'}},
    {'B': {'ABC': '2342', 'QWE': '23442', 'RTY': 'tree'}},
    {'A': {'ABC': '2344', 'QWE': '3424'}},
    {'B': {'ABC': '2344', 'QWE': '2344', 'RTY': 'awed'}}
]
```

Подскажите, есть ли универсальный способ привести его к виду:

```
   A      |      B
ABC | QWE | ABC | QWE | RTY
```

Comment: вы хотите получить в результате "multi-level columns" DataFrame?

Comment: MaxU, да, что-то в этом духе,

Comment: вложенность/глубина списков одинаковая или может быть произвольной?

Comment: MaxU, вложенность глубины будет всегда одинаковая,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

При исходных:

```
l = [
    {'A': {'ABC': '1234', 'QWE': '2342'}},
    {'B': {'ABC': '234', 'QWE': '3424', 'RTY': 'qwert'}},
    {'A': {'ABC': '2342', 'QWE': '23424'}},
    {'B': {'ABC': '2342', 'QWE': '23442', 'RTY': 'tree'}},
    {'A': {'ABC': '2344', 'QWE': '3424'}},
    {'B': {'ABC': '2344', 'QWE': '2344', 'RTY': 'awed'}}
]
```

делаем:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
res = pd.concat([df[x].apply(pd.Series).
                 dropna(how="all").reset_index(drop=True) for x in df.columns],
                axis=1, keys=df.columns).dropna(how="all", axis=1)
```

res, соответственно:

```
      A            B              
    ABC    QWE   ABC    QWE    RTY
0  1234   2342   234   3424  qwert
1  2342  23424  2342  23442   tree
2  2344   3424  2344   2344   awed
```

**UPDATE**

Мне не совсем ясна необходимость преобразовывать словарь в датафрейм, а потом обратно, но...

Если я правильно понял вопрос,то для преобразования полученного фрейма в dash-table нужно будет сделать что-то типа такого (для Flask):

```
data=res.to_dict("records")
data = [{f"{k[0]}-{k[1]}":v for k,v in y.items()} for y in data]
print(data)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": f"{i[0]}-{i[1]}", "id": f"{i[0]}-{i[1]}"} for i in res.columns],
    data = data
)
```

получится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо, чтобы сделать более нагладной таблицу, так:

```
data=res.to_dict("records")
data = [{f"{k[0]}-{k[1]}":v for k,v in y.items()} for y in data]
print(data)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": [i[0],i[1]], "id": f"{i[0]}-{i[1]}"} for i in res.columns],
    data = data,
    merge_duplicate_headers=True,
)
```

тогда получится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, возник дополнительный вопрос, 
возможно ли подобный DataFarame использовать в Dash Table без потери структуры таблицы, соответственно с multi-level columns? буду очень благодарен если подскажите, как можно открыть данную таблицу в dash table с сохранением структуры

Comment: @xcplat я обновил ответ. надеюсь, это то, что вам нужно, потому что я уже давно не брал plotly в руки

Comment: не совсем, есть необходимость отобразить как таблицу в dash_table

Comment: @xcplat обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
from itertools import groupby

data2 = [[(k, k2), v2] for d in data for k,v in d.items() for k2,v2 in v.items()]

res = pd.DataFrame({k: [x[1] for x in g] 
                    for k,g in groupby(sorted(data2), key=lambda x: x[0])})
```

результат:

```
In [151]: res
Out[151]:
      A            B
    ABC    QWE   ABC    QWE    RTY
0  1234   2342   234   2344   awed
1  2342  23424  2342  23442  qwert
2  2344   3424  2344   3424   tree
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @xcplat, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)